# error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor

Tags: typescript, ethereum

I install

```
npm install -g typescript
```

then I want to compile my main.ts class but I always got this error

```
main.ts:14:2 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.
```

My code:

```
import { OrderWatcher, OnOrderStateChangeCallback, OrderWatcherConfig } from '@0xproject/order-watcher';
import { SignerSubprovider, RPCSubprovider, Web3ProviderEngine } from '@0xproject/subproviders';
import { Web3Wrapper } from '@0xproject/web3-wrapper';

let url = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/xxx';
//let url = 'http://localhost:8545';
let provider = new RPCSubprovider(url);
const providerEngine = new Web3ProviderEngine();
providerEngine.addProvider(provider);
providerEngine.start();

let orderWatcher = null;

(async () => {
    // Get all of the accounts through the Web3Wrapper
    const web3Wrapper = new Web3Wrapper(providerEngine);
    const blockNumber = await web3Wrapper.getBlockNumberAsync();
    const networkId = await web3Wrapper.getNetworkIdAsync();

    console.log(blockNumber);
    console.log(networkId);

    //let networkId = 1;
    //let partialConfig = new Partial<OrderWatcherConfig>();

    orderWatcher = new OrderWatcher(
     web3Wrapper.getProvider(), 
     networkId
     );

    //  orderWatcher.subscribe(
    //     ( error: Error|null, orderState?: OrderState ) : void => {
    //         console.log('callback');
    //         console.log(error);
    //         console.log(orderState);

    //     }
    //  );

    orderWatcher.subscribe(
        ( callback: OnOrderStateChangeCallback ) : void => {
            console.log('callback');
            //console.log(callback);
        }
     );

     console.log('end');
})();

console.log('end 2');
```

I have 2 questions?

1. Why I can not use async? Why compiling main.ts throw an error
2. callback always return an error

> Can not convert undefined or null to object

EDIT

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "dom","es2015" ]
  },
  "files": [
    "main.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error message explains it: "Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option."

Comment: @zerkms what that means. Can you give some example please?

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:** How to resolve this depends on the environment in which your JavaScript code is going to run.  You use the `target` compiler option in `tsconfig.json` (or `--target` at the command line) to specify the newest level of JavaScript features that is supported by your runtime environment, and then TypeScript does its best to translate any code that uses features not supported by your `target` level to equivalent code that will work with your `target` level.

Async functions are an ES2017 feature, so if your target environment supports all ES2017 features that you plan to use (see [this chart](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/)), then you can just set `target` to `es2017` and TypeScript will pass the async function through.  Otherwise, TypeScript needs to translate the async function to a function that uses promises, so it warns you if it thinks your target environment may not support promises.  If your `target` is `es6` (same as `es2015`) or newer, then support for promises is guaranteed.  If your target does not support all of `es6` but does support promises, then you can add `es2015.promise` to your `lib` option to tell TypeScript that promises are supported.  Otherwise, you'll have to provide your own promise library.

**Question 2:** To troubleshoot this, I'll need to see the stack trace of the error, for starters.

Comment: Thank you for good description. 

1. I have used "npm install --save @types/es6-promise" but the error is still the same.
2. I will provide full exception

Comment: I have also updated my question with tsconfig.json file example

Comment: #1: Your `tsconfig.json` file has `es2015` in the `lib` option, so you shouldn't be getting the error.  How are you compiling your code?  `tsc` or `tsc -p .` is good; `tsc main.ts` won't use your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Thank you! I spend 2 hours for this. Don't know if I write `tsc ./src/**/*.ts --watch` in my `package.json` tsc don't use `tsconfig.json`.